# Não entendo o por que o empty diz que a variável não esta vazia

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5.3, laravel-blade

Existe um módulo de Membros, onde são cadastrados os membros de uma igreja. Por esse cadastra serão mostrados na pagina principal os aniversariantes do dia em um slide jQuery. Mais quando não tiver aniversariante do dia ele ira mostrar outra coisa. 
Quando nao tem aniversariante com o dd() (dump() end die()) mostra que a variável esta vazia então pensei em fazer assim veja:

```
<div class="col-md-4 col-sm-4 widget footer-widget">
    @if(empty($aniversario))
    <h4 class="footer-widget-title">Redes Sociais</h4>
    <ul class="rslides">
        <li><img src="/imagens/oracao/oracao.jpg" alt="">
            <div>
                <center><h5></h5></center>
            </div>
        </li>
        <li>
    </ul>
    @else
    <h4 class="footer-widget-title">Aniversariante do Dia</h4>
    <ul class="rslides">
        @foreach($aniversario as $aniver)
        <li><img src="/imagens/membros/{{$aniver->imagem}}" alt="">
            <div>
                <center><h5>{{$aniver->nome}}</h5></center>
            </div>
        </li>
        @endforeach
        <li>
            <img id="aniversario" src="/imagens/aniversario/aniversario.jpg" alt="">
        </ul>
    @endif
</div>
```

Onde se a variável $aniversario estiver vazia ele mostrara uma imagem, se não ele entra em loop com as imagens do aniversariante do dia + outra imagem de um parabém.

quando eu faço som `if(isset($aniversario))` ele entra no loop dos aniversariante, mais quando eu mudo a data de nascimento do membro ele não mostra a outra div com o if(empty($aniversario)) faz a mesma coisa mais ao contrario.

Essa imagens mostra o array vazio quando não tem ninguém fazendo aniversário no dia. 
[image: quando nao tem aniversariante]

Mais se eu faço um teste para ver se ele esta mesmo vazia ele diz que não esta ex:

```
@if(empty($aniversario))
    {{ "vazio " }}
@else
    {{"nao esta vazio"}}
@endif
```

E ele mostra estando vazio ele entrar o else.
Ai vc me diz: Então por que você não nega a condição. Também não dá certo.EX:

```
@if(!empty($aniversario)) // mesmo ! negando ele somente faz o contrario mais não mostra a outra imagem
    {{ "vazio " }}
@else
    {{"nao esta vazio"}}
@endif
```

Vocês sabem o que pode ser isso. Como resolver isso?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

O correto seria:

```
@if(isset($aniversario) && $aniversario->count() > 0)
```

porque é uma coleção da classe [Collection](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/collections), e o `empty` não terá o efeito esperado, porque, confere se a variável está vazia, como é uma classe tudo muda, então verifique se a variável existe com [isset()](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.isset.php) e depois pergunte se a mesma tem itens com o método [count()](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/collections#method-count).

<sub>***Referencias:***</sub>

- [Laravel - Collection](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/collections)
- [Collection - count()](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/collections#method-count)
- [PHP - isset()](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.isset.php)

Comment: Verdade man. Muito obg. Relamente. tinha que verificar com o Count mesmo. Mais na vdd isso nem passou pela minha cabeça. Show de bola.

Answer (score 2):

Você pode utilizar o método do proprio collection o `isEmpty()`, ficaria:

```
@if($aniversario->isEmpty())
```

Referência:

- [Laravel Documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/collections#method-isempty)